# Deleting of photos on iOS

Tags: ios, photos, storage

When photos on iOS are added to an album, does that duplicate the amount of space being used? If I add the photos to another app, can I delete them from the camera roll?

Answer (score 1):

No, when photos from the `Camera Roll` are added to an album, it *does not* result in double the storage space being used. The `Photos.app` just tracks those photos as being part of that album, in addition to being in the `Camera Roll` (which is the default album). Note that if you delete these photos from the `Camera Roll`, they will get deleted from the album too (because there's actually only one copy of the photos on the device).

If you add photos from the `Camera Roll` to another app and save, the other app receives its own copy of the photo. You can then delete the photos from the `Camera Roll` and have them only in the other app.